# Why does vuejs router not working with laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I work on Laravel + Vuejs. Something has just happened, since then my script as copied hereunder doesn't work, chrome doesn't detect any vuejs script.
Astonishingly, the same script works well if I copy it into backup directory & run PHP artisan instance from there. Need advise. Actually problem seems with routerview which could not activate due to unknown problem. did i wrongly uninstall something which need to reinstall again ? because seems router doesn't work

kash.blade.php: - Main script

```
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/app.css')}}">
      <link href="{{asset('backend/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css')}}" 
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="{{asset('backend/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" 
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

<body id="page-top">
  <div id="app">
  <div id="wrapper">

      <div class="container-fluid" id="container-wrapper">
          <router-view></router-view>
      </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('backend/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('backend/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('backend/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js')}}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

route.js: - where I describe the component route as to where login.vue lies

```
let login = require('./components/auth/login.vue').default;

export const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: login, name:'/' },
 ]
```

Login.vue: - Just a simple vue script with two text boxes.

```
 <template>
    <div>
 <div class="container-login">
               <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">Login</h1>
              </div>
              <form class="user" @submit.prevent="login">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" 
                    placeholder="Enter Email Address" v-model="form.email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword" 
                  placeholder="Password" v-model="form.password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
                </div>
                <hr>
                </form>
              <hr>
              <div class="text-center">
         </div>
       </div>
  </template>

  <script type="text/javascript">

     export default {
     data(){
  return {
     form:{
      email: null,
       password: null
      }
    }
  }, 
  methods:{

}
} 
</script>
```

Comment: you can check your app.js so you must import vue-router  and check that all vue-router requirements are done well

Comment: tks, everything checked many times, i came here after found no solution. app.js is as follows equire('./bootstrap');


import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

 // Router Imported
 import {routes} from './routes';


const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'history' 
})

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});

Comment: in your route.js try to use import  login  from './components/auth/login.vue'   const routes = [
  {
      path: '/',
      component: login
  },  ]                                                                                                                      instead of                                                                                                                     let login = require('./components/auth/login.vue').default;

export const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: login, name:'/' },
 ]

Comment: you can rerun npm run dev to compile your code, by the way, you said that if you run an old project it will run I would say that the code run because your old project still has the old code compiled. and maybe in the new project the code does not work because you have some errors in your vuejs

Comment: I see that your component name is Login.vue   and in the  route.js  you wrote ./components/auth/login.vue   so if the component is Login.vue you must write ./components/auth/Login.vue

Comment: tks, I tried with import instead of let. but it doesn't work. Also it is login.vue i mentioned wrongly here with caps L. In fact I didn't even touch route.js since yesterday. This malfunctioning occured since this morning before everything work well. I wait further advise

Comment: you can create a new project install vue ,vue-router and insert all your code

Comment: or share all your code files here I will try to fix it for you

Comment: many tks, I remake it again it works. did not find out what had happend